# Fitting a model with only aggregate data for people without outcome

Tags: regression, epidemiology

I am working with surveillance data - I have information on all the people who had outcome Y in a given geographical area in a given time period.

| id | outcome_y | age | sex | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | yes | 27 | f | ... |
| 02 | yes | 84 | m | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 99 | yes | 69 | m | ... |

Crucially, *this table does not include any information on people who *did not* have outcome Y.*

Because the geographical area is fixed, I can use (external) population denominators (even age- and sex-stratified) to calculate an overall incidence risk or rate, as well as stratified incidence rates. I am confident that the surveillance data and the denominator data refer to the same population.

| age | sex | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-4 | f | 425 |
| 0-4 | m | 427 |
| 5-9 | f | 538 |
| ... | ... | ... |

For example, I can calculate the risk in males (of any age) by dividing:

- the count of all cases with sex == "m" in my table,
- by the total number of males in the external population denominator

However, **I'd also like to fit a model**, so I can adjust for more than one covariate at a time - and get measures of effect like a risk ratio, along with confidence intervals.

I've never come across a situation like this before - I'm used to tables that contain information on both cases and non-cases. Is this type of analysis possible, and if so, how could I do that?

Comment: Just to be clear, your surveillance data is at the individual or person unit of analysis, correct?

Comment: @MikeHunter good point. Yes, that's correct: one row in the surveillance table represents a person. The denominator data, on the other hand, is aggregated.

Comment: @MikeHunter oh I see, I could maybe change the level of analysis to population level, turning it into an ecological study, and for example fitting a linear regression model for `rate ~ age_group + sex + ...`?

Comment: Yes, that would work. The literature would describe it as an *exact logistic regression model* which can be fitted using R, Stata, SAS, etc. See Troxler, S., Lalonde, T. L., & Wilson, J. R. (2011). Exact logistic models for nested binary data. Statistics in Medicine, 30(8); https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/exactlogistic.pdf or https://www.stata.com/features/overview/exact-logistic-regression/